# CSS inheritance: parents and childrens' children

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Task: Underline emphasized text inside an ordered list inside any paragraph of the 'note' class. This is what I have so far...

```
.note>p>ol>em{text-decoration:underline;}
```

I'm struggling to get this going. What's' wrong with my code?

***edit: I have also tried this to no avail:

```
.note p ol em{text-decoration:underline;}
```

***edit: This is the HTML I've been using to test it...

```
<div class = "note">
        <p>
        Modifiers are sometimes included along with the basic command, inside...
        </p>

        <table align ="center" border = "3" >
            <td>
                <p>Three things: 
                    <ol type = "i">
                        <li><em>First</em></li>
                        <li>Second</li>
                        <li>Third</li>
                    </ol>
                </p>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: From that the only thing I could think of for you to try is to replace the > with a space...

Comment: `.note p ol em{text-decoration:underline;}`

Comment: Neither can a `p` have an `ol` as a child (or any descendant for that matter), nor can an `ol` have an `em` as a child.

Comment: BoltClock is right, that HTML is a real mess...

Comment: What is your actual HTML, or did you just want random guesses?

Comment: @David Thomas: edited...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because the HTML isn't valid. The OL can not be a child of the P.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

```
A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.
```

So

```
<p class="note">
<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li><em>Two</em></li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ol>
```

and

```
<p class="note"></p>
<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li><em>Two</em></li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ol>
```

are basically the same.

Comment: Thank you, understood. I guess it was a poorly phrased question.

Answer (score 0):

The > operator only gets the elements on the first level. When they are wrapped by any other element like a span for example the selector won't work. Just use

```
.note p ol em { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Example:

```
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <span class="example"></span>
</div>

div.test > span {} /* Only works for the span with the example class */
div.test span {} /* Works for both spans */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.note>p>ol em
```

Just remove the last >,

Or add a class to the list and do

`.class em` (better performance)

Comment: The task is to write a CSS file to style an HTML file, not to change HTML file. ".note>p>ol em" didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The underline the `em` text within the `ol` within the `table` within the `div.note`:

```
.note table ol em {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7xCY3/).

I've left out the implicit elements, because I'm assuming valid HTML, so the `em` can *only* be within an `li` inside of the `ol`; the `ol` itself can *only* be within a `td` (or `th`) inside the `table`.

The `table` *cannot* be within a paragraph (and if you *try* to put it within a paragraph the browser will move that element, unpredictably; but it *will* be moved, since it'll only create a valid DOM tree).